# ReactJS & Flux get data from promise

Tags: reactjs, flux

I am trying to get data from server with service function that I found in a template reactjs project. I do recieve a perfectly fine anwser from the server, I can see the arrays are ok while still in the service, but not when handed over to the component that called for it in the first place. At the component I get a promise object, which has the values (I have seen them in console) but I can't access them. What am I missing?

My component has following function:

```
calculate(dict) {
    var results = Service.calc(dict)
      .catch((err) => {
          var errResp = JSON.parse(err.response);
          console.log(errResp);
          this.setState({responseErrors: errResp});
    });
    this.setState({results:results._handler});
}
```

When I printed the results in to console I saw the Promise object, inside _handler.handler was a value array with my values but I couldn't use them. The error appeared when accessing the results._handler.handler: undefined.

The called service looks like this:

```
class Service {
    calc(dict) {
    return this.handleCalculate(when(request({
        url: UserConstants.URL,
        method: 'POST',
        type: 'json',
        data: dict
    })));
}

handleCalculate(calcPromise) {
    return calcPromise.then(
        function(data) {
            console.log(data); //Success
            return data;
        }
    )
}
```

Meanwhile I use ajax call directly in the component instead of the service. But I understand that is bad practice, how can I get this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi basically you put setState in the wrong place. (It sets state right away without waiting for result getting resolved). It should look like this

```
calculate(dict) {
    var results = Service.calc(dict)
      .then(results => {
         this.setState({results: results});
      })
      .catch((err) => {
          var errResp = JSON.parse(err.response);
          console.log(errResp);
          this.setState({responseErrors: errResp});
    });
}
```

Comment: Indeed! So simple. Thank you for bringing this mistake to my attention.